# How to create a JTable without directly assigning values

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I'm unsure about how to assign values to a JTable without directly assigning values to the initial 2D Array, i.e. `String data[][]= new String[5][5]{"abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno"};`

If I declared my array of 2D String, followed by `defaultTableModel`, is there any way I can assign the values of abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno to the Array/JTable without doing it as above in a separate method maybe?

Update

JPanel invoiceViewPanel= new JPanel(null);

```
String data[][]= new String[4][10];  
String columnHeaders[]={"Invoice ID","Invoice Name","Customer", "Complete?"};  

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnHeaders) {

boolean[] Editable= new boolean[]{
                false, false, false, true
        };

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return editableCells[columnIndex];
        }

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
{
    return columnClass[columnIndex];
}
};

JTable table=new JTable(model);  

JScrollPane tableContainer=new JScrollPane(table);      

final Class[] columnClass = new Class[] 
{
Integer.class, String.class, String.class, Boolean.class
};

 public void launch()
 {
this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    


this.add(invoiceViewPanel);
invoiceViewPanel.add(tableContainer);
this.add(tableContainer);

this.setTitle("Invoices");
this.setSize(500,600);
this.setVisible(true);
this.setResizable(false);

 }
```

This is a basic version of my code. It is just the initialising of my JTable.

I have a text file of the format

> 001/ TV Purchase/ John Smith/ true
>
> 002/ Refrigerator Purchase/ Jean Smith/ false

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) on which we can base an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Swing components work with a `Model`. To update the component you update the model.

So in the case of a JTable you can create an "empty" model for your table by using:

```
String[] columnNames = { "Column1", "Column2", ... };
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Now when you want to add data to the model you can use:

```
Object[] row = {"data1", data2", ... };
model.addRow( row );
```

Read the `DefaultTableModel` API for more methods to change the data. You can also add a `Vector` of data to the model.

Comment: So is this possible in its own method?e.g. `public void tableData  {String row = {"data1", data2", ... };
model.addRow( row );}` ? Where would you call the method? Also is it then possible to pass in a buffered reader? If I had a text file of my data; for example if I had text file of format `John,35,false`, can I get this to string and add to row or is this not possible

Comment: `Where would you call the method?` - I can't answer that. You are the one writing the code. `for example if I had text file of format...` - well you need to format the data into something that the table model understands. For example you could use the `String.split(...)` method to create an Array of Strings and then use the `addRow(...)` method.

Comment: I added some code and text file data if you could offer some advice to my previous comment please?

Comment: @User22, A `String` is not an `Array`. If you look at the API for the methods involved you will notice you need an Array, not a String. You create a `String` by using `String string = "a string";` If you want an `Array` you need to use: `String[] row = {....}.` Sorry, I just noticed I have a typo in my answers. Whenever anybody posts code you need to take the time to understand the concept of the posted code. The code we post is not tested.  Code is updated with proper syntax for creating the Array.

Comment: Also, don't post code segments in comments. The code should be added to you question so it is readable. Finally in your case you can't use a String Array because your Array will contain strings and Boolean values so you need to create an Object Array.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. My program works after days of trying to figure it out. @camickr